# how to count number of links shared by a facebook page?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a website for which it would be useful to know the number of links shared by a particular facebook page (e.g., http://www.facebook.com/cocacola) so that the user can know whether they are 'liking' a firehose of information or a dribble of goodness. What is the best way to get the number of links/status updates that are shared by a particular page?

+1 for implementations that use python (this is a django website) but any solutions are welcome! I tried using [fbconsole](https://github.com/facebook/fbconsole) to accomplish this but I have come up a little short.

For what it is worth, [this unanswered question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7421943/how-do-i-query-links-shared-by-facebook-pages) seems relevant. As does the fact that, as of 2012.04.18, you can export your data to csv from the insights management page on the facebook site. The information is in there I just don't know how to get it out...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event that anyone else finds this useful, I thought I'd post [my gist example](https://gist.github.com/2421193) here. fbconsole makes it fairly simple to extract data through the [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

The caveat is that it was not terribly easy to programmatically extract data through fbconsole so I wrote the `fbconsole.automatically_authenticate` to make it much easier to access this information in a systematic way. This addition has not yet been incorporated into the [master branch of fbconsole](https://github.com/facebook/fbconsole) (it was just posted this morning), but it is available [here](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/fbconsole) in the meantime for those that are interested.

Comment: I have same problem too, but I can't use this sample code. Have you any working sample? Thanks